# Json overwriting previous line

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a huge problem with my code and I wasn't able to find anything on the internet for the past 3 hours so I'm asking here. I'm trying to add the ctx.guild.id as a new variable to my json "queue.json" file but apparently every time I run this code, instead of adding a new variable in the new line it overwrites the previously added variable. Here's my code:

```
with open("queue.json", "r") as f:
    Queue = json.load(f)
    if not ctx.guild.id in Queue:
        with open("queue.json", "w") as QueueAddFile:
            NewQueueID = {ctx.guild.id : []}
            json.dump(NewQueueID, QueueAddFile, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Comment: You cannot assign multiple value to a key in a json file so when you do this it basically overwrite the old value.

Comment: @AnatoleSot But it only runs when the ID is not already in the dictionary

Comment: You're not adding `ctx.guild.id` as a new key in the json, you're making it the *only* key. You need to do something like `Queue[ctx.guild.id] = []` and write `Queue` back to the file.

Comment: ctx.guild.id is always a different number, so there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: Again, *you're not adding a new key here*. The json that you write to the file *only contains your new value and nothing else*. You've thrown away whatever used to be in `Queue`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding the key to the `Queue` dictionary, you're creating a new dictionary that just has the one new ID in it. So when you rewrite the file, you're discarding all the other keys.

```
with open("queue.json", "r") as f:
    Queue = json.load(f)
if ctx.guild.id not in Queue:
    Queue[ctx.guild.id] = []
    with open("queue.json", "w") as QueueAddFile:
        json.dump(Queue, QueueAddFile, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Comment: Thank a lot! It works perfectly as desired, I thought that I can't use Queue[Variable] if this variable isn't already in the file itself

Comment: You can't *read* `Queue[variable]`, but of course you can *write* it. How else do you create new dictionary entries?